# Specific regex function

Tags: php

I have a database with member ID values. (always 8 digits long)
If member is on the pay list there is a "SI" prefix added to the ID.

For example:

```
John: 12345678

Jack: SI87654321
```

Now i would like to write a function which checks if there is "SI" at the beginning of the number. (Some kind of regular expression which extracts the "SI" from the number)

If yes -> return ID number (without SI), YES radio button is checked. (checked="checked")

If not -> return ID number, NO radio button is checked. (checked="checked")

example:

PHP:

```
$ID = get from database (for example: SI12345678)

function check () {return $pureNumber}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<?php echo $pureNumber ?><br/>
<label for="dz1"><input type="radio" value="SI" name="davzav" id="dz1"/>YES(SI)</label>
<label for="dz2"><input type="radio" value="" name="davzav" id="dz1"/>NO</label>
</body>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just check the first two characters:

```
if( substr($id,0,2) == "SI") {
    $is_si = true;
    $id = substr($id,2);
}
```

Comment: looks great and simple. What about the checkboxes? Do you think this is okay? : <?php if($is_si==true) {echo "checked='checked'"; } ?>

Comment: That's exactly right (although personally I'd just put `if($is_si)` - comparing it to `true` is redundant)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regular expressions for this:

```
if (0 === strncmp($userid, 'SI', 2)) {
    echo "SI number: ", substr($userid, 2);
} else {
    echo "Not SI number: ", $userid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want to do this in one line with a regular expression, the following code will return your number.

```
$result = preg_replace("/^SI/", '', $in,  1);
```

Then, compare the $result value to the $in value.

```
if ($result != $in) { checked = "checked";}
```